# Explain how JavaScript converts type implicitly when both types are not equal?

Tags: javascript

Does right side of operator is forced to convert to type on left?

`number == string -> number == number`

Are both sides converted to same underlying type, like number?

`boolean == string -> number == number`

Are there different rules of every operator `*-/+||&&%`??

I've looked at other question/answers they are unclear and confusing.

Comment: Does it matter what type it is converted to? what matters is that `==` normalises to comparable types. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: it matters...@AvinKavish for example to know whether this is true or not you need to know what is going on as in what are values being converted to first.  `fasle == "0"` if they are being converted to number first then it's true as `0 == 0` otherwise they are being convert to boolean then it's `false == true` as string is true

Comment: @AvinKavish—yes, see the [*Abstract Equality Comparison* algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

Comment: Ok i see, it's never been a problem for me because I always use strict comparison with explicit type conversion.

Comment: that'd be ok if you always read your own code, if you are reading someone else code then you will end up in situation where `==` are used. This is also asked in interviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are given in the [*Abstract Equality Comparison* algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

> Does right side of operator is forced to convert to type on left?
>
> ```
> number == string -> number == number
> ```

Step 4: If `Type(x)` is Number and `Type(y)` is String, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.

So yes.

> Are both sides converted to same underlying type, like number?
>
> ```
> boolean == string -> number == number
> ```

Step 6: If `Type(x)` is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.

which gives different types (number and string), so it goes to Step 4: `number == ToNumber(y)`.

So yes again.

> Are there different rules of every operator *-/+||&&%??

Other operators may do coercion of the result of evaluating the expression so I guess "Yes". Read the relevant parts of [*ECMA-262#expressions*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

When type conversion is involved in the comparison (i.e., non–strict comparison), JavaScript converts the types String, Number, Boolean, or Object operands as follows:

- When comparing a number and a string, the string is converted to a
  number value.  JavaScript attempts to convert the string numeric
  literal to a Number type value. First, a mathematical value is
  derived from the string numeric literal. Next, this value is rounded
  to nearest Number type value.
- If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted
  to 1 if it is true and +0 if it is false.
- If an object is compared with a number or string, JavaScript attempts
  to return the default value for the object. Operators attempt to
  convert the object to a primitive value, a String or Number value,
  using the valueOf and toString methods of the objects.
- If this attempt to convert the object fails, a runtime error is
  generated. Note that an object is converted into a primitive if, and
  only if, its comparand is a primitive. If both operands are objects,
  they're compared as objects, and the equality test is true only if both refer the same object.

Answer (score 0):

`==` converts the operands to the same type before making the comparison.

For **relational abstract comparisons** (e.g., <=), the operands are first converted to primitives, then to the same type, before comparison.

Strings are compared based on standard lexicographical ordering, using Unicode values.

Read the [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:

1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
3. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.
4. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison `Number(x) == y`.
5. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.
6. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.
7. If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison `x == ToPrimitive(y)`.
8. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison `ToPrimitive(x) == y`. Return false.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]